# If $D$ is an integeral domain and $D$ is of finite characteristic, prove that the characteristic of $D$ is a prime number.

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing

If $D$ is an integeral domain and $D$ is of finite characteristic, prove that  the characteristic of $D$ is a prime number.

I tried to solve this as:

We know that,
The characteristic of an integral domain of a finite characteristic,
$D$ is the least of all $p$ such that $\underbrace{a+a+...+a}_{\text{p times}}=pa=0,\forall a\in D.$

Since, $D$ is of finite characteristic,  so there must exist an $m$ such that $m\in \Bbb Z^+ $ such that $\underbrace {a+a+...+a}_{\text{m times}}=ma=0$ for all $a\in D.$

If $m$ is a prime, then we are done.

If $m$ is not a prime then there exists two non-zero positive integers $r$ and $s$ such that $r,s\neq 1$ satisfying $rs=m.$

Now, let $a,x\in D$ such that $a,x\neq 0.$ Then, $$(m)(ax)=0\implies [\underbrace {ax+ax+...+ax}_{\text{rs  times}}]=(\underbrace {a+a+...+a}_{\text{r times}})(\underbrace {x+x+...+x}_{\text{s times}})=0\implies (ra)(sx)=0.$$

We note that, $ra,sx\in D$ but as, $D$ is an integral domain $ra=0$ or $sx=0.$ Now, similarly, we have, $rx=0$ or $sa=0.$

If say, $ra=0$ then, as $a$ is an arbitrary element of $D$ so, all non-zero elements have order $r,$ as $r\neq 0.$

Otherwise, if $sx=0$ then, as $s$ is an arbitrary element of $D$ so, all non-zero elements have order $s,$ as $s\neq 0.$

But then, $r,s\lt m$ so, characteristic of $D$ is less than $m$. This implies $m$ is not a characteristic of $D.$ This is a contradiction.

So, $m$ is prime.

---

Now, my question is can  the above proof in my approach be more elegant? Is it lacking any details? How can I make this look more better by making it shorter preferably. All in all, is there any way to improve the readability of this proof to make it simpler and better.

Lastly, if there are any errors in my proof, please do let me know.

Comment: Your proof is correct. To make it more "elegant", i would suggest to just apply your definition of characteristic to the element $a=1$ the multiplicative unit of the ring. Then, the minimum $m = 1 +\cdots +1 = 0$ cannot be factorised since you are in an integral domain.

Comment: I don't know to add more "focus". I tried my best. So, I feel the close vote is unnecessary under this circumstances

Comment: I think you should say "positive characteristic" rather than "finite characteristic" because the only characteristics assigned are nonnegative integers, and $0$ would still be considered "finite" (unless you're a physicist with some hangup about "finite=nonzero" ...)

Comment: @rschwieb My terminologies along with it's usage are precisely and precautiously taken from I.N Herstein 's book, so you might be talking about some other definition, which is very much possible considering the scenario and the usage of the terms.

Comment: @ThomasFinley Ok, shame on Herstein then :). That said, there have definitely been those who have flirted with calling characteristic 0 "infinite characteristic."  It's just very uncommon

Comment: @rschwieb Maybe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. To make it more "elegant", i would suggest to apply your definition of characteristic to the element $a=1$ the multiplicative unit of the ring. Then, the minimum $m = 1 +\cdots +1$ such that $m=0$ cannot be factorised since you are in an integral domain.